# State undefined in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am using the latest react version 6.0.2
I am following lama dev youtube video to make the shopping website using react.
I want to pass the state(using redux) and its data to the success page and then use the 'cart' and its 'products' and all its information to further save orders.
In the video this was done using "useHistory()" method I am using useNavigate() (this works in React router dom v6) for it. I am struggling to parse the data further to get the desired cart and products which is showing null. I am getting the state but cart and products are showing null in the Redux state in dev tools.

My success page looks like this

```
const Success = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    console.log(location); // to see what state are being passed after placing an order

    const data = location.state;
    const cart = location.state.cart;
    console.log(data, cart);
    const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);

    const [orderId, setOrderId] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const createOrder = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await userRequest.post("/orders", {
                    userId: currentUser._id,
                    products: cart.products.map((item) => ({
                        productId: item._id,
                        quantity: item.quantity,
                    })),
                    amount: cart.total,
                    address: data.billing_details.address,
                });
                setOrderId(res.data._id);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };

        data && createOrder();
    }, [cart, data, currentUser]);

    return (
        <Container>
            {orderId
                ? `Order has been created successfully. Your order number is ${orderId}`
                : `Successfull. Your order is being prepared...`}
            <Link to="/">
                <Button>Go to Homepage</Button>
            </Link>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default Success;
```

My cart page looks like this

```
const Cart = () => {
    const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
    const [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState(null);
    // const history = useNavigate();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const onToken = (token) => {
        setStripeToken(token);
    };

    //token returns on successful order placing
    console.log(stripeToken);

    useEffect(() => {
        const makeRequest = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment", {
                    tokenId: stripeToken.id,
                    amount: cart.total * 100,
                });

                navigate("/success", { state: res, cart });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
        stripeToken && makeRequest();
    }, [stripeToken, cart.total, navigate]);

    return (
        <Container>
            <Navbar />
            <Announcement />

            <Wrapper>
                <Title>YOUR BAG</Title>
                <Top>
                    <TopBotton>CONTINUE SHOPPING</TopBotton>
                    <TopTexts>
                        <TopText>
                            <ShoppingBag
                                style={{ margin: '-3px 2px', color: 'teal' }}
                            />{' '}
                            BAG(3)
                        </TopText>
                        <TopText>
                            <Favorite
                                style={{ margin: '-3px 2px', color: 'red' }}
                            />{' '}
                            WISHLIST(0)
                        </TopText>
                    </TopTexts>
                    <TopBotton type="filled">CHECKOUT NOW</TopBotton>
                </Top>
                <Bottom>
                    <Info>
                        {cart.products.map((product) => (
                            <Product>
                                <ProductDetail>
                                    <Image src={product.img} />
                                    <Details>
                                        <ProductName>
                                            <b>Product:</b> {product.title}
                                        </ProductName>
                                        <ProductId>
                                            <b>ID:</b> {product._id}
                                        </ProductId>
                                        <ProductColor color={product.color} />
                                        <ProductSize>
                                            <b>Size:</b> {product.size}
                                        </ProductSize>
                                    </Details>
                                </ProductDetail>
                                <PriceDetail>
                                    <Hr />
                                    <ProductAmountContainer>
                                        <Add />
                                        <ProductAmount>
                                            {product.quantity}
                                        </ProductAmount>
                                        <Remove />
                                    </ProductAmountContainer>
                                    <ProductPrice>
                                        ₹ {product.price * product.quantity}
                                    </ProductPrice>
                                </PriceDetail>
                            </Product>
                        ))}
                        <Hr />

                        {/* <Product>
                                <ProductDetail>
                                    <Image src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9558241/pexels-photo-9558241.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260"/>
                                    <Details>
                                        <ProductName><b>Product:</b> HAKURA T-SHIRT</ProductName>
                                        <ProductId><b>ID:</b> 124541</ProductId>
                                        <ProductColor color="grey"/>
                                        <ProductSize><b>Size:</b> M</ProductSize>
                                    </Details>
                                </ProductDetail>
                                <PriceDetail>
                                    <Hr/>
                                    <ProductAmountContainer>
                                        <Add/>
                                        <ProductAmount>2</ProductAmount>
                                        <Remove/>
                                    </ProductAmountContainer>
                                    <ProductPrice>$ 30</ProductPrice>
                                </PriceDetail>
                            </Product> */}
                    </Info>

                    <Summary>
                        <SummaryTitle>ORDER SUMMARY</SummaryTitle>

                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText>Subtotal: </SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>₹ {cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>
                        </SummaryItem>

                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText>
                                Estimated Shipping:{' '}
                            </SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>₹ 150.90</SummaryItemPrice>
                        </SummaryItem>

                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText>
                                Shipping Discount:{' '}
                            </SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>-₹ 150.90</SummaryItemPrice>
                        </SummaryItem>
                        <Hr />
                        <SummaryItem type="total">
                            <SummaryItemText>Total: </SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>₹ {cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>
                        </SummaryItem>

                        <StripeCheckout
                            name="Ecofelx"
                            image="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/Ardent10"
                            billingAddress
                            shippingAddress
                            description={`Your total is ₹ ${cart.total}`}
                            currency="INR"
                            amount={cart.total * 100}
                            token={onToken}
                            stripeKey={KEY}
                        >
                            <Button>CHECKOUT NOW</Button>
                        </StripeCheckout>
                    </Summary>
                </Bottom>
            </Wrapper>

            <Footer />
        </Container>
    );
};

export default Cart;
```

Here look at the redux screenshot. I want the cart, its products and grab their respective id's so that I can place that order at the backend and ship to its address.
[Redux screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj5x6.png)

EDIT: My updated approach
I realized that useSelector() in the cart.jsx is used there to grab the state cart and then that cart is being passed on the success page which is further used to make orders. I used useSelector() again in the success to grab the cart there instead of passing through the navigate.

//My cart.jsx

```
 const cart = useSelector((state)=>state.cart);
    const [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState(null);
    // const history = useNavigate();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const onToken = (token) =>{
        setStripeToken(token);
    }

    //token returns on successful order placing
    // console.log(stripeToken); 

    useEffect(() => {
        const makeRequest = async () => {
          try {
            const res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment", {
              tokenId: stripeToken.id,
              amount: 500,
            });

            navigate("/success", {state:res});
          } 
          catch(err)
          {
              console.log(err);
          }
        };
        stripeToken && makeRequest();
      }, [stripeToken, cart.total , navigate]);
```

// My success.jsx page now

```
const location = useLocation();
    // console.log(location); // to see what state are being passed after placing an order

    const cart = useSelector((state)=>state.cart);
    const data = location.state;
    console.log(data,cart);

   

 

    const currentUser = useSelector((state)=>state.user.currentUser);

    const [orderId, setOrderId] = useState(null);
    console.log(orderId);

    useEffect(() => {
    
        const createOrder = async () => {
            try {
              const res = await userRequest.post("/orders", {
              
                  userId: currentUser._id,
                  products: cart.products.map((item) => ({
                    productId: item._id,
                    quantity: item.quantity,
                })),
                amount: cart.total,
                address: data.billing_details.address,
              });
              setOrderId(res.data._id);
            } 
            catch(err) {
                console.log(err);  
          }
        };

        data && createOrder();
      }, [cart, data, currentUser]);


      return (
        <Container>
          {orderId
            ? `Order has been created successfully. Your order number is ${orderId}`
            : `Successfull. Your order is being prepared...`}
          <Link to="/">
            <Button>Go to Homepage</Button>
          </Link>
        </Container>
      );
    };
```

result screenshot ->
[result console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj5x6.png)

Comment: It's not clear what your redux state has to do with sending route state other than where you are passing the `cart` state to the success page via route state. Can you clarify this part of your question/issue?

Comment: The reason to send the data and the cart is that when the success page is shown to the user, On the backend all the details of the product and the user who placed this order need to be sent to the Order route so that a successful order is placed. I am posting the data to the orders route. I am new to react and redux and this is my first project. This is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y66RgYMAgSo at [1:21:00] is where my main problem is. This video was made on react-router-dom 5.3.0 I am using 6.0.2.

Comment: Thankyou for your time. I am a beginner and I tried to implement using your answer but my redux dev tools is showing mw the cart and product chosen but inside my cart.jsx page data and cart and undefined. I stuck at this for 3 days now. Thankyou anyways.

Comment: I don't see what your issue may be from the youtube video. They even pass the state as `data` as I suggested in my answer. Is the issue that your `Success` component isn't seeing the correct route state? You are using function components and React hooks so I don't see how there would be much of a difference between the `react-router-dom` versions in this regard. Can you share a more complete code example? How are you declaring the routes? Can you provide enough context for us to reproduce the issue? Can you fork your code into a *running* codesandbox that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: I uploaded all the files of my project on code sandbox-> https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-kare-km41d?file=/client/src/pages/Cart.jsx   along with the package.json for respective dependencies. There is a client side and and api side. Along with this i uploaded my entire project till now on github-> https://github.com/Ardent10/DWOC
But I am not sure if this will work or not, Because to run the project that you may need .env file that holds stripe publishable/security keys only then we will be able to make a payment.

Comment: You may need to scale that codesandbox back. Is the stripe checkout code necessary? You can likely mock those components. I also can't even get the home page to render when that's the only route.

Comment: Thankyou sir. I think I figured it out. Using you knowledge and watching some react router dom videos I think I grabbed the concept of useSelector() again in my Success to grab my cart from the state. I will edit my question, please correct me if I am wrong anywhere

Comment: I see, so saving the cart data into your app state (redux) and retrieving it on the success page, and also sending some stripe session/purchase data in route state to the success page. Seems logical. So this is all working for you now?

Comment: Yes, I can see the respective order placed in my MongoDB collection Would you mind If I can ask you more doubts till I finish this project ? there are some features that I want to customize and are not done in the video.

Answer (score 0):

You are only sending a `res` object in route state, missing is the `cart` state.

```
const res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment", {
  tokenId: stripeToken.id,
  amount: cart.total * 100,
});

navigate(
  "/success",
  {
    state: res, // <-- only res sent in route state
    cart,
  },
);
```

Route state should be an object with ***all*** the state you want to pass.

```
const data = await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment", {
  tokenId: stripeToken.id,
  amount: cart.total * 100,
});

navigate(
  "/success",
  {
    state: {
      data, 
      cart,
    },
  },
);
```

Destructure both correctly from route state in success page.

```
const { state } = useLocation();
console.log({ state });

const { data, cart } = state || {};

console.log({ data, cart });
```